# Replacing my current CMS

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm currently using a very simple CMS which I coded myself in PHP and mysql. It's main purpose is to add news articles and reviews. I've had some issues with security at times and uploading images. Would it be fairly simple to implement something like Joomla to my static existing html pages which are coding linking to my database?

Any help or nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What about WordPress? While it is a fat pig, it may be not that hard to make a custom theme based on the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly how complex your site is, what your plans for the future are, and whether you'll ever have any collaborators, you might want to avoid Joomla. It's a very big, complex piece of code, with a lot of features. Joomla assumes a lot about your site, adding weight which may be unnecessary. For example, Joomla will always create a session, using its own database storage, whether you require sessions on your site or not [*].

If you want something a bit more lightweight, take a look at [Perch](http://grabaperch.com) or [Kirby](http://getkirby.com). Both are excellent, simple applications for web content management.

[*] Caveat: I am *not* a very experienced Joomla user (have been using 1.5 for about 6 months), so take the details of what I say with a pinch of salt, but bear the general point in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really just need something basic so that helps a lot, I was always reluctant to use joomla despite people saying I should ad I really don't want sessions and don't need a lot of features it offers. I'll try one of the above. Thanks again.